# I installed the kernel 3.1.2-030102-generic and the update manager proposes me to install the 3.0.0-14 kernel

Tags: kernel, update-manager

On "security updates" of the update manager appears the following list:

- headers files relates to linux kernel version 3.0.0 (linux-headers-3.0.0-14 - new installation)
- linux kernel headers for version 3.0.0 on x86/x86_64 (linux headers-3.0.0-14-generic - new installation)
- generic linux kernel headers (linux-headers-generic)
- linux kernel headers for development (linux-libc-dev)

Do you advise me to install them even though I installed the kernel 3.1.2? Or on the contrary I can ignore them without any problem?
I use Ubuntu 11.10.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have installed v3.1 of the kernel manually and you have not changed your `GRUB_DEFAULT` value in your Grub2 file (`/etc/default/grub.cfg`)

In that case, you can let Update Manager to continually update the 3.0 kernel.  You will always boot into your later kernel.

Its best to leave the system continually updating the v3.0 kernel.  Two reasons:

1. You'll have an alternative boot kernel if for whatever reason, the kernel 3.1 stops working (e.g. you could have installed a new kernel module etc)
2. You can occasionally test to see if the latest updates fixes your original issue that forced you to use the v3.1 kernel in the first place...

Note - you should be managing your kernel 3.1 updates on a regular basis to get the latest security updates and stability updates etc.

Comment: Exactly, I installed it manually and I haven't changed the grub_default value.
Ok thanks, so I can let "update manager" to continually update the 3.0 kernel. But just a curiosity: since I uninstalled all the old kernel versions, isn't it now a bit useless to have the kernel 3.0 which is more old than 3.1.2? Or is it necessary in any case?
Many thanks for your help

Comment: I can think of at least a couple reasons why you should leave it updating... answer updated.

Comment: Ok, you're absolutely right. From this moment on I'll keep at least two kernel versions ;)

Thank you very much!!!